# variable not printing the xml tags

Tags: xml, variables, xslt-2.0

I am using the below code:

```
<xsl:template name="employmentdates">
    <xsl:variable name="empdates">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="employment_information/job_information" group-adjacent="emplStatus">
        <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key() = 'A'">
            <xsl:variable name="Low">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="start_date"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <emp_info>
                <start_date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$Low"/>
                </start_date>
            </emp_info>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$empdates"/>
</xsl:template>
```

In this I have defined a variable empdates and in that variable I am trying to make a small xml file. But when I am trying to print the variable empdates 
using the xslt code `<xsl:value-of select="$empdates"/>` then its only printing the content value (which is dates eg: 2016-10-20 ) and missing the xml tags emp_info and start_date.

I am expecting something like:

```
       <emp_info>
            <start_date>2016-10-20</start_date>
        </emp_info>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `xsl:value-of` does - it creates a text node. You want `xsl:copy-of`.